# NuGet packages in Xamarin.Android (Firebase messaging)

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had some problems with installing last versions of NuGet packages for Firebase Messaging, so I installed older versions, and now there is an exception (Actually it is warning but project can't be started with it).

```
Warning Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

Packages which I already Installed: 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 - v22.2.1 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat - v22.2.1 
Xamarin.Firebase.Common - v32.940.0-beta3
Xamarin.Firebase.Iid - v32.940.0-beta3
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging - v32.940.0-beta3 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement - v32.940.0-beta3 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks - v32.940.0-beta3

Consolidate in Manage NuGet Packages didn't solve the problem.
Help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

`google play service base` version and `Firebase` version is depended on support v4 and v7 version. And your support v4 v7 version is too old. Need to update.

I suggest you delete your support v7 v4 library and install `google play service base` stable version 32.961. Xamarin will help you to install the The corresponding version of v4 v7 library.

`Google Play service base` 32.961  and `Firebase` 32.961 are depended on support v4 v7 24.2.1.